# Finding error in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, as

What is wrong in the following sentence?
**"As I am tired so I shall sleep early tonight."**

It seems alright to me but apparently it has an error somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not word it this way (as you did in your comment in another answer):

> We cannot use a 'so' after an 'as'.

Both of those words are flexible words with different usages, and a "rule" like that will likely get you into trouble.

Here's the problem with the sentence in your question. In that context, the first word (*as*) is being used to essentially mean 'because', and the second (*so*) is being used to mean 'therefore'. That's why the repetition doesn't work. Does this sentence look okay to you?

> **Because I am tired therefore I shall sleep early tonight.**

(Perhaps the awkwardness off that structure is more glaring when we use the bigger words.) No, instead we'd say one of the following:

- Because I am tired I shall sleep early tonight.
- I am tired, therefore I shall sleep early tonight.

Comment: @theraven - I thought that someone should explain a little more, even if you understand it now. (Someone might visit this question later wondering the same thing.)

Answer (score 1):

You'd use either

> As I am tired I shall sleep early tonight.

or

> I am tired so I shall sleep early tonight.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer and can you clear a doubt for me. Can we not use a **'So'** after an **'As'**?.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to use 'So' after 'As' the way you tried to, no. It would be possible to use 'So' in another way, like:
"As I am so very tired I shall be heading to bed"